# IE6 performance issues with adding className on multiple elements (jQuery tableHover plugin)

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer-6, addclass, classname

In an application I write that uses a large HTML table of numbers the design requires that the row and column of the hovered cell will be highlighted.

I develop all the JS for this project using jQuery 1.3.x, and I found the **tableHover** plugin that does exactly what I need.

But:

on IE6 the performance of this plugin drops down as the number of cell elements rise to a point where the page is almost unresponsive.

I thought that the problems lies in the plugin and I actually rewrote it's entire functionality from scratch, just to discover that I have the same performance issues.

After debugging the code I now know that selecting a large amount of elements plus applying **className** (**jQuery.addClass()**) is extremely slow on IE6.

I tried to use **jQuery.css()** instead with only **background-color**, the performance is better, but again, when the number of table cells rise the performance drops to an unusable state, and on all other browsers the performance of **jQuery.css()** is way slower than **jQuery.addClass()**.

The main problem here is that there is no common parent to a table column, so in order to style a column one needs to traverse the entire table, select each row and then find the right *nth-child* **td**. my jQuery code for this one looks like that:

```
//col_num is the current td element
//table is the parent table    
var col_num = cur_cell.prevAll().length + 1;
var this_col = $('tr td:nth-child(' + col_num + ')', table);
```

I won't paste my entire code here because it's irrelevant for the issue.
The only answer I'm looking for is: Is there a known method to do what I need in a better performance margin? I'm not looking for "Chrome" performance speed, just something faster than "non responsive".

Thnaks

Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with performance complex jquery on very large tables in **IE6**. Here is what i can offer you in terms of help:

- encode **as much** data in the html as possible. for example, encode the row number and col numbers in the TDs class or name attribute
- add a mouse listener to the **entire** table, and then use event.target to get the TDs
- parse out the location of the cell you are hovering form point #1
- again, you will probably have to add a ton of classes, but have a class for each column and each row, that way you can select both entire row and entire column with 2 class selectors, and add css to them
- **cache as much as possible**. if the user moves from one cell to another, check if its in a row you have already highlighted. i think this is pretty much guaranteed to happen, so you will have 1/2 the selector operations
- cache entire columns you have selected, so you dont have to select twice, same for rows
- check out this responsiveness [**plugin**](http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2008/12/jquery-responsiveness-plugin-for-fast.html) i wrote, you may want to use it.
- also, there is [**another**](http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2009/02/building-fast-jquery-plugins.html) post i wrote on the topic of writing fast jquery plugins.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried to avoid encoding data in the HTML (adds complexity from the server side..), a parent eventHandler and caching...It's just a visual effert. but I guess you are right, for the sake of compatibility I need to uglify my code.

Comment: IE6 is the greatest uglifying agent in web dev

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the number of className changes and subsequent reflows by letting the browser's CSS matching engine do the work for you. For example, for a 3x3 table:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sel-row-0 .row-0 td, .sel-row-1 .row-1 td, .sel-row-2 .row-2 td,
    .sel-col-0 .col-0, .sel-col-1 .col-1, .sel-col-1 .col-1 {
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<table id="foo">
    <tr class="row-0">
        <td class="col-0">a</td>
        <td class="col-1">b</td>
        <td class="col-2">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="col-0">d</td>
        <td class="col-1">e</td>
        <td class="col-2">f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
        <td class="col-0">g</td>
        <td class="col-1">h</td>
        <td class="col-2">i</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now all you need to do is set className on the outer table to "sel-row-(num) sel-col-(num)" and all the cells will update at once, which will be much quicker than looping and setting classes.

For a very large number of cols/rows the amount of data in the stylesheet can become unwieldy. You can get around this a bit by dynamically changing the rules in the stylesheet through the document.styleSheets list, but this takes some cross-browser work that jQuery won't help you with. Or for a table with, say, many rows but few columns, you can put the selected-row class directly on the row, and only do the column highlighting this way, which is still only 2-3 class changes.

(It would be nice if we could use the CSS3 nth-child selector as you did in the jQuery selector, but browser support isn't there yet.)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether in searching for better responsiveness from jQuery, you're not seeing the forest for the trees?

Why don't you include a `<colgroup>` element at the top of your table (either explicitly or, if necessary, by adding it dynamically with jQuery) and then assign a background color value to the column matching your selected cell's index?

IE6 does support the `<colgroup>` element, but only in limited properties.  However, background-color is one of those supported so this should see a significant improvement in your performance.

Comment: WTF? Was that answer really that unhelpful or wrong?  Why was it downvoted? Someone's showing bad SO etiquette.

Comment: Beats me. You might not need `colgroup` (`col` on its own should do), but, yeah, seems to me like it should work, for the limited range of styles that work with columns.

Answer (score 1):

I should have noted this - I'm a much better CSS/HTML developer than a Javascript one, I tried every non-script method I know before digging into JS.

I actually started from **colgroup**, I even use it for column widths on the same table, but the **colgroup** and **col** elements are set visually behind the table elements, so if **tbody**, **tr**, **td** or any other element in the table has a background (which in my case, many of them has), **colgroup** will not show over these elements, and it did not respond to positioning or any other advanced CSS manipulation I tried to apply on it.